# I'm generous with upvoting, but can't earn vox populi badge?

Tags: support, voting, badges

On two different days I maxed out my vote quota, but only 38/40 votes appear in my stats, so I haven't earned my badge. And I'm not voting for junk just to earn the badge, either -- I'm new and I've been upvoting quality stuff in my tag preferences/areas of expertise. I've just happened to max out more than once and observed that I haven't acquired the badge to indicate my generosity and discernment....

Comment: You must use a certain amount of your votes on questions, not just answers, to get up to 40 votes. Have you been doing that?

Comment: Perhaps. Haven't noticed, didn't know it mattered. So it counts against my max limit but not toward the badge? Hmm. I guess I simply won't earn the badge unless I just happen to not upvote any deleted/closed questions/answers out of all 40 that day.

Comment: If a post you voted on is deleted, that vote is returned to you.

Comment: Oh yes. I notice and upvote both depending on how good they are. It's especially important to a couple obscure tags I follow, to de-weed.

Comment: OK, I see. But I'm still informed, at least by the iOS app, that my limit is reached and to "try again in 3 hours", for whatever reason. I'll pay closer attention going forward using the actual website.

Comment: If you ran out of votes at 38 in a day, you are not voting on questions enough to earn the badge.

Comment: Interesting. The silver and gold badges are awarded so long as at least 25% of the votes went towards questions, and I'm pretty certain at least 1 in 4 of my upvotes today were for questions, if not half.

Comment: Are you afraid of downvoting, or am I reading your title wrong?

Comment: downvoting is a privledge user doesn't have, @Dedup.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't have enough rep to down-vote. I have no moral position against it, no.

Comment: @sss4r: Yes, my bad. Forgot your rep by the time I read the last comment. Wish you luck getting enough.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to vote on at least 10 questions before you vote on 25 answers. Once you've voted on 25 answers the vote countdown starts and you can only vote 5 more times.

If a post is deleted the same day as your vote was cast, you get that vote back. So you can exceed the 30/40 limits if you vote on posts that are deleted.

Comment: OK, this answer appears precise and definitive. However, as I said, I am not deliberately voting to earn the badge, so I am not keeping track of the ratio. I guess it'll be awarded when by chance this requirement is met.

Comment: @sss4r Don't worry, when you get the downvoting ability there'll be plenty of deserving questions appearing in almost any tag you'd like to meet the requirement. There's no rush. :)

Comment: @TZHX: I was going to upvote that comment but I hit my daily limit, so you'll have to wait another twenty-some minutes. ;) (How's that for serendipity, eh?)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But why anybody since more than 2 years doesn't have taken the time to correct the informative message displayed for VoxPopuli from "use the maximum 40 votes in a day" to "use the maximum 40 votes in a day with at least 10 questions" or something similar ? I think that I'm not the first to have this problem ... and I'm certainly not the last.