# Maximum upvotes in a day but no Badge

Tags: discussion, badges

In order to earn the **Vox Populi** badge, are there a fixed number of questions and answers to be voted upon ?

This has happened to me twice.
I voted on 12 questions and after 26 votes on answers, I had reached my daily limit. And didn't get the badge.

Comment: Patience, grasshopper, it takes a while to run the check script sometimes. Also, make sure you *actually* used all votes, some votes are reserved for questions and can't be used if you do too many answers first.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can upvote neither questions nor answers. I can just upvote comments now

Comment: @BillWoodger I got your joke but the badge still hasn't shown up

Comment: It is possible to use all your votes and not get Vox Populi if you are voting mostly on answers.

Comment: *Sips coffee*, grabs fountain-pen to begin writing ... "Patience, Grasshopper : My life on Meta.StackOverflow , Trials and Tribulations; The Early Years. Memoir . New Orleans: 2005."   ... :P

Comment: Pf. It most certainly can still be reproduced. I guess it's a dupe, but that's a different close-reason.

Comment: @Coffee I think "Eager learner" would be a more suitable batch for me.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi - keep it up : - )

Comment: related: [I'm generous with upvoting, but can't earn vox populi badge?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295661/im-generous-with-upvoting-but-cant-earn-vox-populi-badge)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4927751/kshitij-saraogi?tab=topactivity) you've only voted 36 times today. Of course you could have voted for some questions that have been deleted but it's more likely you voted on 25 answers before voting on at least 10 questions. Once you've voted on 25 answers the vote countdown starts and you can only vote 5 more times.

Comment: The "next badge" bit on their profile says 38, and is not I believe affected by caching.

Comment: Still short of 40 though.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't disagreeing with your point.